# What data type are the analog pin labels (A0, A1, etc)?

Tags: pins, analogread, data-type

Arduino Mega

I would like to have an array containing analog pin labels something like...

```
int analog_pins[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3};
int num_analog_pins = sizeof(analog_pins) / sizeof(analog_pins[0]);
```

Is this possible? It has compiled without any warnings or errors but I'm dont have my board with me (yes beginners mistake) so cant really check if it works.

Comment: Read the wiki entry, it should give you a good understanding of the **sizeof** operator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [Arduino.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Arduino.h), the analogRead() has `uint8_t` as parameter. You can define them as `byte` or `uint8_t` and you don't have to use the sizeof().

The type of A0 is defined in the file [pins_arduino.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h):

```
#define PIN_A0 (14)
static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
```

Nevertheless, what you have with integers is 100% okay as well.

When you don't have a Arduino board available, you can use the simulation of an Arduino Uno at [Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/).

---

As @DataFiddler writes below this answer, using a 'const' keyword is preferred:

```
const uint8_t analog_pins[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3};
```

Comment: `const uint8_t analog_pins[]` might even be better, eventually allowing for a lot of compiler optimization

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation will be correct for num_analog_pins, however it's convention to use the *type* of the array like so

```
int num_analog_pins = sizeof(analog_pins) / sizeof(int);
```

As @Jot noted, you'd save much space by declaring your array using uint8_t like so

```
uint8_t analog_pins[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3};
uint8_t num_analog_pins = sizeof(analog_pins) / sizeof(uint8_t);
```

Comment: `sizeof(uint8_t)` :-) very formal

Comment: @Juraj haha indeed!  I've always written such code for portability and clarity.

Comment: @RamblinRose You should write `uint8_t num_analog_pins = sizeof(analog_pins) / sizeof(analog_pins[0]);`

Comment: @MarkSmith I'm confused by your comment - sizeof returns the number of bytes allocated for an array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array_type) = number of array elements.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't seen the denominator there. Comment deleted.